# FPE panels replaced

Tags: electrical, wiring

Does any of you who is electrician know if my home insurance can refund me for having the Federal Pacific E panel and wiring replaced? 
I got it replaced with new one because I was warned that the house is in danger if I won't have it replaced. I got it replaced and paid a lot of money for it.

Does anyone has experience if insurance can cover it somehow?

Comment: The only way to know is to ask your insurance company.

Comment: I will ask them and let people know.

Comment: Who warned you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about insurance claims, not home improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your insurance company told you to replace it, you should have negotiated any terms before doing so. I rather doubt they did.

If an electrician told you to replace it, that's called "selling a product with fear, uncertainty and doubt" and the "selling" part should have been obvious from the "paid a lot of money to do so" part of the transaction. If you failed to shop around or seek quotes from other electricians before having the work done, that's on your head.

Replacing worn-out, defective equipment is not an insurance claim - it's called maintenance, and is part of owning a house rather than renting one.

Comment: you are right, even though I think it's not fair to mess with people like this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to say no way. There were never any recalls on FPE panels or breakers, and regardless of their reputation it is not mandatory to have them replaced.

You can always try to put a claim in saying the panel was damaged or something, but I don't think you're going to get anyone to pay for this for you. Besides, you are bordering on insurance fraud with claiming anything like this. I'd contact your agent before doing anything.

It's simply a home improvement, insurance doesn't cover that.

Comment: if it's not mandatory why do they tell you that you must have it replaced otherwise it can cause fire. And actually it was damaged. The circuit breaker was damaged and when I tried to replace it the new one couldn't snap it in so it was just hanging there. By knowing this I didn't want to risk a danger of possible fire or damage...

Comment: Who is "they" ?
By damaged I mean physically damaged, not just from age or wear.

Comment: electricians ...

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet the "insurance company" did not write to you with *You must replace your service panel because it is dangerous.*

More likely, that message was delivered orally.  The actuaries would love for you to reduce their risk at your expense.

If your policy or another written document from the insurance company or your state insurance commission says anything to the effect that the insurer will pay for replacement of dangerous items in the house, then you are covered.  If not, the expense is all yours, unless you can persuade them to provide a rate reduction.

Despite the obvious logic of paying to reduce risk, it is exceedingly rare for an insurance company to do so.  The only instance of that I know of is State Farm— which insures about 1 in 3 vehicles on the road—paying for safety improvements at the [10 most dangerous intersections in the U.S.](http://americancityandcounty.com/news/government_state_farm_names).

Comment: yeah, I ave State Farm